Remove 1 of the applied styles to a paragraph with multiple styles applied?
I have a problem in Microsoft Word:
In my enumerated (multi-level) list, multiple styles are applied to the paragraphs:
(List Paragraph; Numbered; Heading 3; ... (a bunch of custom styles)), one of which (Heading 3) I don't want to be applied to it because it makes the elements show up in the table of contents.
However, when I try to remove it from the Style Name field in the Apply Styles pane, Word keeps auto-completing to add it to it.
How can I remove just one of the applied styles to a paragraph?
Thanks!

The Built-In Heading styles are special and cannot be deleted.
Change to a different paragraph style, perhaps a custom one.
See How to deal with advanced numbering in Word? for more on setting up numbering.

I don't want to delete the heading style from the style set, I just want it to be no longer applied to the paragraph in question.

You no longer want the numbering for the paragraph? or You no longer want it to appear in a Table of Contents? What prevents you from simply applying a different style to the paragraph, perhaps one that looks the same but does not have numbering. You could create a new style based on the one and modify that style to turn off the numbering.

When I try to change all the X styles that are applied to the paragraph and type the name of the style I want to replace them with, Word just adds the new style to the ones that are applied already and I end up with a paragraph to which X + 1 styles are applied.

I do not understand. A paragraph can have only one paragraph style applied to it. Perhaps you are using the term "style" to mean something else.
